# How to obtain the current website URL in my theme?

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, theme-development, customization

I am working on a custom theme and I have the following doubt about how to correctly insert the link to some section of my website into the theme.

If you open this link you can understand what I need to do: `http://localhost/wordpressAsper/`

As you can see under the header slideshow I have 3 boxes that are links.

I need to link the second box (the one named **Archivio**) to this page: `http://localhost/wordpressAsper/archivio-2/`

I know that I can simply put this URL into the href attribute of my a tag but this is not a smart idea because then I have to moove the website on my remote webserver.

So I am thinking that should exist something like a wordpress function to retrive the current URL of the website.

What is the best way to implement this thing?

Tnx

Comment: Note that `localhost` simply points to your own computer. :) We won't see anything there (other than our own things :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[bloginfo('url')](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) should get you the URL for the installation.

EDIT:

I guess you could also use [get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

Comment: Note that this would return _home_ URL, which is usually but not necessarily same as _site_ URL.

Comment: You are correct but using that will take into account if core is installed in a sub-directory won't it?

Comment: Ehm, never mind... My brain wandered away into front page logic insanity. :) "home" would be correct for front-end URL here (and "site" for admin).

Comment: In special cases, such as, I'm using Polylang and when I visit a second language page bloginfo('url'); takes me to something like http://theurl.com/french. So using home_url() seems more robust.

Answer (score 1):

As posed in question the way to retrieve the current URL to the root of the site would be [`home_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/home_url/) for site's front-end.

However there are multiple functions that deal with URLs to specific kinds of pages. It's not clear what you are linking to (post? page? archive?), but there are likely specific URL-forming function for it which should be used over constructing such URL "manually" from the root address.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bloginfo('url') but also can use get_option function, check documentation:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

and by the way we cannot access your localhost :)

Answer (score 0):

The global `$wp` object contains the current request, which can be used to get the current URL anywhere on the site. A helper function like the following demonstrates how this works:

```
function wp157715_current_url() {
    global $wp;
    $current_url = trailingslashit( home_url( $wp->request ) );

    return $current_url;
}
```